# Load gzip data fast with Python

Tags: python, load, query-optimization, gzip

I have a large file (~500 Mo) that contains a dictionary of dictionaries like this :

```
{'data1': {..},
 'data2': {..},
 'data3': {..},
  ...  }
```

This file is saved as gzip (using Python) to optimize memory. Now I query a lot this file, so when I want to get just 'data2', I need to load it all and look for data2, which takes time in loading & memory. Is there a way to load only the element we want ? Or at least to load faster the file ?

Thank you,

Comment: use pyspark i guess

Comment: I don't find the results in the correct format with pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start reading from the middle of a gzip stream. You need to start from the beginning and read until you find what you're looking for. However you do not need to read the whole thing into memory. Just read small chunks at a time, giving the chunk size to `read()`.

For fast access, I would recommend copying your data into an [sqlite3 database](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Yes I ended up working with sqlite3! Thanks :)